# How do I load a .pkl file into torch?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm trying to work with [stylegan3](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan3). My goal is to freeze previous weights and biases in the model and add an extra layer to the model which allows me to specialize the images. My question is, how do I load the models then? Because every attempt I have made at loading the files has resulted in some kind of error.

I figured out that I need to load in the model with the following code:

```
device = torch.device('cuda')
network_pkl = "https://api.ngc.nvidia.com/v2/models/nvidia/research/stylegan3/versions/1/files/stylegan3-r-ffhq-1024x1024.pkl"
with dnnlib.util.open_url(network_pkl) as f:
    G = legacy.load_network_pkl(f)['G_ema'].to(device) # type: ignore
```

However, I do not know how to freeze this model and add an additional layer to it!

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

Upon more googling I figured out that this is how you freeze the layers. Now I just need to add an additional layer to the model. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what errors you get.  Please also include your code.

Comment: @ewokx Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question

Comment: What happens when you run that?

Comment: @ewokx It didn't crash, which I assume that means it worked. Also, I think I figured out how to freeze the model. I just need to add a layer now.